# How to provide child class of document in OASIS API for Filenet

Tags: document, atom-feed, filenet, oasis

We are trying to use OASIS API to create a document in Filenet through Atom. We tried different syntax but not working. If it's just cmis:document it's working but if we change that with any leaf class of document it's not supporting. Does anyone worked with OASIS API to interact with FIleNet for a custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the IBM website found answer. We were confused by following similar syntax "cmis:document". We were passing as "cmis:leafclass". But eventually came to know if you are passing leaf class no need of cmis: present. You just need to pass "leafclass". Below link for reference.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014928326